# Gradle adds all modules as EJBs in application.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle, build.gradle, ear

I have the following EAR project in my Gradle script having 2 deploy dependencies:

1. An EJB jar
2. An EJB client jar

What I want to do is create an EAR with the 2 jars in ear root but only the actual EJB jar in application.xml, i.e. something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="6" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">
 <display-name>MyEJBEAR</display-name>
 <module>
    <ejb>MyEJB.jar</ejb>
 </module> 
 </application>
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
project(':MyEJBEAR'){
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
            deploy project(':MyEJBClient')
            deploy project(':MyEJB')
            earlib <common jars>  
        }   
}
```

The produced EAR structure is what I want however it contains an application.xml file like this (i.e. adds all deploy dependencies as EJBs):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>MyEJBEAR</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>MyEJB.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>MyEJBClient.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

I have tried to play with deploymentDescriptor like this but I had no luck:

```
ear {
        deploymentDescriptor{
            module("MyEJB.jar", "ejb")
        }
    }
```

Any idea on how could I exclude the MyEJBClient.jar reference from the application.xml file?

**EDIT**:

I have found a workaround solution to this by throwing my existing (IDE Generated) **META-INF** folder that contains a valid application.xml from the EAR project root to a dir(e.g. MyEJBEAR/resources) and adding the following
lines in `project(':MyEJBEAR')` closure:

ear {

```
appDirName = 'resources'
```

}

This done based on [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ear_plugin.html#sec:using_custom_app_xml) section of Gradle Documentation but I still need to somehow **generate** a valid application.xml from my build script.